# Why does partition flip from rw to ro unasked and how do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, partition, ext4

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 `kernel 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP (26Nov2019)` on a cheap HP laptop with 8G of memory and 1TB hard drive.

I have three partitions:

- /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi (automatic mount)
- /dev/sda2 on /home/ok/old (manual mount)
- /dev/sda3 on / (automatic mount)

Two days ago the root file system was apparently damaged somehow.  I have no idea how.  I keep up to date with patches.  The battery indicator has always been unreliable: it will show 18% remaining and the next thing it shuts down.  I was about to get the machine to reboot using fsck on /.

My plan before doing anything else is to copy all my files to a newly purchases 1TB external drive.  I'm not using duplicity because one side effect of whatever happened is that it no longer recognises its own files.  So I'm using `tar czf`.  The first attempt got up to about 70GB but reported that certain directories could not be read.  I tried to fix that with `find . -type d -exec chmod a+rwx {} +` but this reported that the file system was read-only.  Somehow the mount had changed from

```
/dev/sda2 on /home/ok/old type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

to

```
...                                 (ro,...)
```

spontaneously.

I umounted `/dev/sda2`, mounted it again, changed the directory permissions and restarted.  This time tar got to 122GB of output before complaining

```
[<number>,<number>] EXTA4-fs error (device sda2):
__ext4_get_inode_loc:4642: inode #<num>: block <num>: comm tar: unable to read itable block
```

in dmesg and

```
tar: <filename>: cannot state: Input/output error
```

from tar. Many times.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to change anything on the disk -- the file system sounds like it has been damaged (or maybe even the disk) and OS is flipping it to r/o to protect the data.  If you are running your `tar czf` as root, you shouldn't need to mess with the mode (the error you got might also be symptomatic of the damage in the f/s).  An uncontrolled shutdown sounds like a prime candidate for causing f/s corruption.

Comment: I recommend using `gsmartcontrol` to view the SMART attributes of your hard-drive. If "reallocated sector count" or "offline uncorrectable" is larger than zero (and increasing), your hard-drive is probably dying. Could you check?

Comment: Create on the new disk a partition at least as big as `/dev/sda2` (let's call it `/dev/sdb2`) and copy data byte by byte `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb2 bs=8M`. Afterwards you can `fsck` the partition `/dev/sdb2`.